# Save response from $http service to an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, callback

Following is the code, which is consoling the response but unable to set the response to store in `$scope.dateWiseData` array. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
$scope.dateWiseData = [];
var tmpArr = [];
var x = 0;
for (var i=0; i< 7;i++) {
    $http.post('/api/getdata', {_id: currentUser._id, data: data}).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        tmpArr.push(response);
        if ( x < 7 ) {
            $scope.dateWiseData = tmpArr;
        }
        x++;
    });
}
console.log("--Week Data Array--");
console.log($scope.dateWiseData);
```

Comment: I would create an array of promises, 6 in your case, and use $q.all instead. What you posted looks fine, but the problem is when will you be able to tell it's all been finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to print the `console.log($scope.dateWiseData);` this will execute before the `$scope.dateWiseData` array is assigned to  data which means this will print before the data is getting from server. but your data should be assigned to that array after the http is completes. You need to check the promises in javascript

```
$scope.getData() = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    for (var i=0; i< 7;i++) {
        $http.post('/api/dayavailability', {_id: SessionService.currentUser._id, weekDay: new Date($scope.sevenWeekDayArr[i]).toISOString()}).then(function(response){
            tmpArr = response.data;
            if ( x < 7 ) {
                $scope.dateWiseData.push(tmpArr);
            }
            if(x==6) {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
            x++;
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

wrapt that for loop like this
and

```
$scope.getData().then(function() {
   // processing
});
```

** Dont forget to add $q in as a parameter in the controller **

Comment: yes `{{dateWiseData}}` use this in the view and u can print the values on the page

Comment: ok..data is populating in the view but what if I need to use the `$scope.dateWiseData` later in my controller, how do I do this ?

Comment: didnt get that. could u please describe a bit :)

Comment: post your full angular controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61822/discussion-between-trialcoder-and-kalhano-toress-pamuditha).